# Can a third party ask for an annulment if neither married person wants it to happen?

Tags: catholicism, annulment

Say that a couple was married despite an [impediment](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P3Y.HTM), which is usually justification for annulment. Some examples of impediments include:

- One of them was abducted (*raptus*, or [bride kidnapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bride_kidnapping)) and has been under the kidnapper's control since to the point of developing [Stockholm syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stockholm_syndrome).
- The two are close blood relations and there is an issue of [consanguinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consanguinity).

Now let's say that both married people do not wish to have their marriage annulled. Can a third party, such as their families, ask for an annulment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but Canon Law provides a specific method:

> 1674. The following are qualified to challenge a marriage:
>
>       1. the spouses;
>       2. the promoter of justice when nullity has already become public, if the convalidation of the marriage is not possible or expedient.
>
> [[CIC](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P6K.HTM)]

For a marriage to be challenged, the family must first prove the nullity in public (for example, criminal bigamy, or lack of consent, or prohibted consanguity) which would prove the marriage civilly invalid, and then present the promoter of justice with that evidence for him to petition the Marriage Tribunal for sacramental nullity.

The [promoter of justice](http://www.vatican.va/resources/resources_glossary-terms_en.html) is "the person appointed in each diocese and in the higher tribunals of the Catholic Church whose responsibility it is to provide for the public good." The relevant tribunal will be able to identify the particular person in its case.

Comment: In case you would like to mention this: the "promotor of justice" is analogous to the "district attorney" or the "prosecutor" in the criminal justice system. The diocese appoints one whenever a really contentious case arises (usually in order to investigate grave ecclesiastical crimes). For marriages, the promotor of justice would only intervene in the most notorious cases; so this would never be the “normal” way to begin the process of declaration of nullity.

Comment: @AthanasiusOfAlex Agreed, it wouldn't be normal, because normally one of the spouses starts the petition. Where the spouses don't want to, but someone else does, canon law only provides that way -- and my three examples probably would be notorious.

Comment: So to clarify, the family can't directly ask for an annulment, but they could ask for a promoter of justice to do it on their behalf?

Comment: Yes but. And it's a big but. As I understand it from the canon and @Athanasius' comment, the nullity of the marriage must already have been proved publicly before going to the tribunal's promoter of justice.

Comment: @Thunderforge If this is a real situation for you, then the opinion of a couple of random bods on the internet (however knowledgeable or apparently knowledgeable) should be no substitute for actually consulting a real-life canon lawyer. It becomes a pastoral advice question, and we don't give pastoral advice.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Nope, not a real situation, just a curiosity about how the annulment process works.

Comment: This looks like it is really for obvious, blatant cases where everyone knows there is a serious problem. It isn't for "oh, I think Aunt Mabel maybe looked a little distracted or tipsy before her wedding and I don't like her husband, so I'm going to get them annulled <maniacal laughter> even though they get along really well."